# mysql incremental change

Tags: mysql

We are developing an ongoing system using MySQL. The database might be changed according to product requirement. I am looking for some code or tool to upgrade my MySQL schema on dev, stage and production. Requirements:
1. It does the incremental without causing data loss
2. It can translate between schema and database instance. So when I have 10 patches, I can  aggregate them into a new database schema.
3. Stable. I don't want the translation process to result in different schema that is hard to track.
4. Better to have ability to compare database or schema.

Comment: How did you achieve the solution?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL WorkBench can do it.  . . . .

Comment: Oh? I should have to look to it then :) Thanks